# What would "F.S." abbreviation mean on 1841 Census Record for Billin household in Helston, Cornwall?

Tags: 19th-century, census-records, cornwall

On the 1841 Census Record for my 3rd great grandparents John Billin and Mary Symons, there is a notation that I am keen to clarify.

The record for this family starts at the bottom of one page and show that John is a 25 year old Mercer and Tailor living with Mary aged 25.

[image]

At the top of the next page their two children Joseph (2 years old) and William (6 months) are enumerated along with a Catherine Sampson, aged 20, who has what looks like "F.S." written in the "Occupation" column.

[image]

The same abbreviation appears elsewhere on these two pages against four other women aged from 20 to 75 years, and I think it may be short for "Female Servant".

Can anyone confirm that this is the likely or certain meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I should have searched harder before asking because I just found this abbreviation recorded on a page entitled [Abbreviations Used On Census Returns
England & Wales 1841-1891](http://www.genuki.org.uk/big/eng/LIN/census_abbrev.txt) where it says:

> F.S. ~ Female Servant (1841 Census)